# When submit edit , value getting null from Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here's my code
Edit Function when I try to submit, value getting null and unable to edit.

```
$("#opendialog").click(function () {
    var clonetext = $('#infor').clone(true);
    $('#previewDiv').html(clonetext);
    $("#previewDiv").dialog("open");
    return false;
});

$(function () {
    $("#previewDiv").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        transition: "pop",
        buttons: {
            "Edit": function () {
                $("form").submit();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a basic form with only two button and click event attached to them. Refer this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/hJaEk/) demo**, might be helpful to you !

JS:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 300,
width: 350,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    "Create an account": function() {
        alert('create');
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        alert('close dialog');
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
}
});


$( "#create-user" )
.button()
.click(function() {
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```